# Microsoft Graph API Unknown Error when retrieving user's calendars - Client Credentials Flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to get a user's calendars list using Microsoft Graph via Postman. I am using Client Credentials flow and I have Admin Consent for these permissions:

```
Calendars.Read
Calendars.ReadWrite
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Mail.Read
Mail.ReadWrite
User.Read.All
User.ReadWrite.All
```

When calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my_user_id_here}/calendars
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "b0214447-98f6-42e7-9424-d3ee4862a25b",
            "date": "2018-09-11T09:05:05"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the HTTP status code is 401. I would say that I have all the required permissions. What am I missing?

Comment: Getting the low hanging fruit out of the way. Can you confirm that this user has a mailbox setup in Exchange Online within this tenant? Also, can you confirm if you can open this mailbox in OWA (https://outlook.office365.com)? Finally, can you add the token you're getting back to your question? The token helps sort out which scopes are actually being applied, not just which ones are being requested.

Comment: OP were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

The 401 means Unauthorized. Where have you set the permission? The permission need to config with the app we use(

**GraphScopes**: in the Web.Config file of MVC project/appsettings.json file in the NETCore project
)

Or just for Postman test, you need to register the app in the Azure Active Directory Application Registration(not in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

> And blog from Azure Active Directory Developer Support Team: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-client-credentials/

Answer (score -1):

I have also added an azure directory application and the result is the same. I added all the possible permissions in AD app.

Comment: Downvoted. This is not an *answer*. Forums have posts about others having problems. The beauty of question and answer sites (like StackExchange is) is that "noise" shouldn't be there, and only a problem that the OP and future visitors have and possible solutions to it are shown. This could be a comment on the question, if there appears to be value to the original problem is saying it.